# How to forward XAMPP to domain

Tags: dns, xampp, server, public, portforwarding

I have a computer running XAMPP on 192.168.1.X:80 and that port forwarded, along with a domain I can set nameservers and/or zone records on.

Security risks aside, how do I set the domain so I can go to mydomain.com and see my XAMPP server?

Edit: I can verify that my port forwarding works, I just need to be able to access it through my domain, not the 12.345.678.90:1234 address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse my bad english.
One of the ways is:
Visit http://www.noip.com and Sign in. There you'll get your Domain. You'll have to get location on the file 'host', modify your hosts file using this link http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file

Comment: So edit your host file and you'll can use your domain.

Comment: That's the part I forgot. :-) Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I helped. :-)